# UPDATE/INSERT based on if a row exists

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Working on some postgreSQL queries. As I said in a previous question..my knowledge of SQL logic is quite limited..

I have this query that inserts a row.

```
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d G:i:s.u');
$check_time = "start"; //can also be stop
$check_type = "start_user"; //can also be stop_user

$insert_query = "INSERT INTO production_order_process_log (
production_order_id, 
production_order_process_id, 
$check_time, 
$check_type) 
    VALUES (
'$production_order_id', 
'$production_order_process_id', 
'$timestamp', 
'$user')
";
```

Unfortunately, that is adding a new row every time. I would like to add conditional SQL so that

if the production_order_process_id doesn't exist, do the INSERT as it's written in the query above. That is, add the new row with all the new information

but if the `production_order_process_id` does exist and the `check_type` is `stop_user` then UPDATE the row to fill the column `stop` with the `$timestamp` and fill the column `stop_user` with `$user`.

I understand this is complicated.. Or, at least for me it is ^^ Thanks much for the help!

Comment: The standard SQL would be `MERGE`. But I don't think Postgre supports it? Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-postgresql

Comment: @podiluska very quick google makes me think maybe not as well :( is there any other way? I will look into a postgresql `MERGE` or substitutes more..

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually called  `MERGE` or upsert. PostgreSQL doesn't have explicit support for this operation.

The best article I've seen on the topic of `MERGE` in PostgreSQL is [this one by depesz](http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/) .

Comment: Why is merge better than using conditional logic to test if the fields are NULL? Thanks!

Comment: So that if `start`i is `NULL` i put `$timestamp` into it, but if it has a value, i put it into `stop`…

Comment: @thomas  Concurrency, basically. Think about what an concurrent change to the record you are examining will do. You can use a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` if to avoid that if you are careful but it won't work in all circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if you can create a **stored procedure** and call while insert new record.

```
    DELIMITER $$

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `DB`.`InsertNewRow` $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE `db`.`InsertNewRow` ()
    BEGIN

    DECLARE V_EXIST INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE   V_check_type VARCHAR(20);


    SELECT production_order_process_id,check_type INTO V_EXIST,V_check_type FROM production_order_process_log;

    IF V_EXIST=0 THEN

      INSERT INTO production_order_process_log (
      production_order_id,
      production_order_process_id,
      $check_time,
      $check_type)
        VALUES (
      '$production_order_id',
      '$production_order_process_id',
      '$timestamp',
      '$user');

    ELSEIF V_check_type='stop_user' THEN


      /* UPDATE QUERY HERE */

    END IF;
    END $$

    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, stored procedures are going to have to wait until I can migrate this database into something my mySQL or msSQL like. Having my server tech trying to install the postgresql PDO packages earlier this week caused some pretty major problems. I know that they're included in PHP for mySQL. Though postgre has worked for me for a long while, I can't wait till I'm using mySQL!

Answer (score 1):

After insert type ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...

Comment: yes, but don't forget to give the column(s) that you want to be used as keys an INDEX or UNIQUE INDEX

Answer (score 1):

Use `MERGE` statement

Here is the usage

```
MERGE INTO table [[AS] alias]
USING [table-ref | query]
ON join-condition
[WHEN MATCHED [AND condition] THEN MergeUpdate | DELETE]
[WHEN NOT MATCHED [AND condition] THEN MergeInsert]

MergeUpdate is
UPDATE SET { column = { expression | DEFAULT } |
          ( column [, ...] ) = ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) }
[, ...]
(yes, there is no WHERE clause here)

MergeInsert is
INSERT [ ( column [, ...] ) ]
    { DEFAULT VALUES | VALUES ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] )
[, ...]}
(no subquery allowed)
```

I'm sure you'll find more articles/examples if you search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just ad a WHERE CLAUSE to the insert:

```
INSERT INTO production_order_process_log   
           (  production_order_id, production_order_process_id, check_time, check_type)
    VALUES ( '$production_order_id', '$production_order_process_id', '$timestamp', '$user')
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
        FROM production_order_process_log nx
        --
        --  assuming production_order_id is the Primary Key, here
        --
        WHERE nx.production_order_id = '$production_order_id'
        );
```

UPDATE: I was confused by the parameters and the VALUE() . The fragment below works without parameters, but
with *immediate* values:

```
INSERT INTO tmp.production_order_process_log
           (  production_order_id, production_order_process_id, check_time, check_type)
    SELECT 1, 2, '2012-07-19 12:12:12', 'Lutser'
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
        FROM tmp.production_order_process_log nx
        --
        --  assuming production_order_id is the Primary Key, here
        --
        WHERE nx.production_order_id = 1
        );
```

(you'll have to change it a bit to re-add the parameters)

Comment: I apologize, but this is _just a bit_ over my head. production_order_id is the primary key for production order. what is nx? sorry if really basic confusion >< ..

Comment: The nx is the *correlation name* (aka as alias) for the subquery. The subquery tests if a row exists (for production_order_id=1) and returns True or False. And yes: it is really basic. And: this syntax *is* supported by postgres. (I tested it!)

Comment: If you add the parameters again (sorry, I don't know PHP), dont forget to replace the literal '1' by $1; also in the subquery.